# C invalid memory access

Tags: c, pointers

I am new to C language and I'm trying to compare the characters a pointer points. But when I inspect my code with Intel Inspector for memory errors I am getting invalid memory access errors in this function.
Inspectors says that these two lines cause this.

`for (int i = 0; currentPathParameter[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
         if (currentPathParameter[i] == '/')
}`

Whole function:

```
bool asteriskControl(char* currentPathParameter) {
int directory = 1;
for (int i = 0; currentPathParameter[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    if (currentPathParameter[i] == '/')
        directory++;
}
if (asteriskCounter > directory) {
    printf("Can not use '*' operator for the folder that the program is currently in.");
    return false;
}
return true;}
```

This is the line that I call the function.

```
noAsteriskError = asteriskControl(currentPath);
```

I am passing currentPath to function and I initialize it here.

```
char* currentPath = NULL;
char erdem[12] = { 'e','r','d','e','m','/','h','a','k','a','n','\0' };
currentPath = strdup(erdem);
```

Minimal code example:

```
int asteriskCounter = 1;
bool asteriskControl(char* currentPathParameter) {
int directory = 1;
for (int i = 0; currentPathParameter[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    if (currentPathParameter[i] == '/')
        directory++;
}
if (asteriskCounter > directory) {
    printf("Can not use '*' operator for the folder that the program is currently in.");
    return false;
}
return true;}

int main() {
char* currentPath = NULL;
char erdem[] = "erdem/hakan";
currentPath = strdup(erdem);
bool noAsteriskError = false;
if (asteriskCounter > 0)
    if (currentPath != NULL) {
        noAsteriskError = asteriskControl(currentPath);

    }
    else {
        noAsteriskError = false;
    }
else {
    noAsteriskError = true;
}
return 0;}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is `currentPathParameter`? Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I was trying to post more parts of my code. I accidentally published it like this. I'm sorry about that. I'm trying to edit now.

Comment: You still haven't answered the first question in the first comment.  And really, a [mcve] would be useful here.

Comment: Hello. If you use your function without passing it a `\0` terminated string (char*), the loop will never stop. Your sample code cannot be compiled since `asteriskCounter` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: When, where and *how* do you call this `asteriskControl` function? What are you passing to it when you call the function? How do you initialize (if at all) the pointer or array you pass to the function?

Comment: currentPathParameter is a char pointer that is null terminated. I forgot to mention asteriskCounter. It is an integer type global variable.

Comment: On an unrelated note, why not do e.g. `char erdem[] = "erdem/hakan";`? And why not pass `erdem` directly to the function (arrays naturally decay to pointers to their first element)?

Comment: There is no point actually. You're right. My bad.

Comment: In your real and actual code, between `currentPath = strdup(erdem);` and `noAsteriskError = asteriskControl(currentPath);`, there's no other assignment to `currentPath`? If you catch the crash in a debugger, what is the value of `currentPath` and `i`? Where is `currentPath` pointing? What is the contents at that location? If you build with verbose warnings (using `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic` if using `gcc`, or add `/W4` if using Microsoft Visual Sudio), do you get any warnings from your actual code?

Comment: There is no other assignment to currentPath right now. I was planning to do it later. I don't get any warnings or whatsoever. I don't catch any crashes in debugging mode.

Comment: So you don't get any crash when you run in a debugger? Then that could be an indication that `currentPath` isn't really initialized. Some debuggers initialize memory, sometimes to zero which for a pointer will be a null pointer (on a PC-like system). If you have null-pointer checks those will work fine when running in the debugger. But when not running in a debugger, local variables will be uninitialized and have an *indeterminate* (and seemingly random/garbage) value. Then the null-pointer check will not work. Please check the actual code (because the code you show isn't the one crashing).

Comment: I have used w4 mode and I got some warnings. I'm trying to fix it right now. I didn't see the w4 message first time. I'm sorry about that.

Comment: Only warning I'm getting right now is C4244. char temp = fgetc(); causes this.

Comment: .prog.d:1: *** missing seperator. stop. I was trying to run it on the link you mentioned but I got this error and I don't know how to fix it. Can you help me please?